# Getting values in separate html tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have a goal of performing validation based on input from two separate html tags. I am wondering how to retrieve both values, concatenate them into a string and then send the concatenated string as an argument into a function for my controller?

```
<input type="hidden" id="country_code" name="country_code" value="<%= @user.phone_no(:country_code) %>" />

<input name="country_code" id="country_code" value="<%= @user.phone_no(:country_code) %>" size=4 type="text" readonly="readonly" class="validate[required] finput" />
```

What should my call to the javascript be like where I get both country code and phone number from each of these tags?

Comment: first change id of elements, no two elements can have same id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try...

```
var full="";
$("input").each(function(){
full += this.value
});
console.log(full)
```

Comment: @RPV : To be more specific you can use $("input[id=country_code]").each(function(){
 full += this.value
 });

Answer (score 0):

First of all, 'id' should not be same for the two html tags.First change the id as following(you can take an name).

```html
<input type="hidden" id="country_code_hidden" name="country_code" value="<%= @user.phone_no(:country_code) %>" />

<input name="country_code" id="country_code" value="<%= @user.phone_no(:country_code) %>" size=4 type="text" readonly="readonly" class="validate[required] finput" />
```

Then the javascript can be,

```js
var value1 = $('#country_code').val();
var value2 = $('#country_code_hidden').val();
value3 = value1.concat(value2);
```

Then, send this value3 as an argument to your function.

Comment: Ever heard of semicolons?

Comment: Yes, Thank you. @max

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery. Each html tag can be identified by its id. So you can get its value and from there concatenate the values of two different tags. Then call a validate function like your current JavaScript call is.